# what is difference between 0 and infinity norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose  $f$ is a real function on $\Omega$, both $\|f\|_\infty$ and $\|f\|_0$ are defined as
$\sup_{x\in \Omega} f(x)$ in many books. Then, am I missing some from their definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context that these are functions on a *compact* topological space $X$, the $C^o(X)$ norm is the sup norm, which, in the context of Riesz and others, is a limit of $L^p$-norms, so, called the $L^\infty$-norm.

For non-compact $X$, the continuous functions usually need not have finite sups, etc, so there'd be a divergence of notation and concept.

That is, obviously abbreviations and economy are desirable and useful, and/but the specific choices are heavily dependent on context: not only *when*, but "which demographic".

Comment: thanks. By $C^0(X)$, you mean all continuous functions on $X$? Not $C_0(X)$, the one all continuous functions vanishing at infinity? In particular for $X$  non-compact.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the potential ambiguity: $C^o$ is meant to be _all_ continuous functions, in contrast, as you say, to $C^o_o$ or $C_o$, which would be continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the books that you've read, but when I've seen it, the $0$-norm is defined differently.  Some books define $\|f\|_0$ as $|\{x|f(x)\neq 0\}$, that is, the measure of the support of $f$.  Equivalently, for finite-dimensional vector spaces, $\|f\|_0$ is the number of non-zero elements.  Strictly speaking, this is an abuse of terminology since the "$0$-norm" is not really a norm since it does not have the property of scalability.  However, it can be said to arise as the limiting case of the $L^p$-norm as $p\to0$.